# How to transfer the columns together and then sort them out in R

Tags: r

I  have 20 columns and here is part of the sample for providing data:

```html
df <- read.table(text = "Id1    Id2 Id3 Id4 Id5 Id6 Id7 Id8
Ali.J   koli.M  Handy.M kori.Z  Simon.B James.K Moli.Z  kori.Z
Smith.kol   Hoddy.G Nancy.M kori.Z  Simon.B Khan.M  Moli.Z  Peter.K
Kato.Bada   Ahadi.M Nancy.M kori.Z  Simon.B Khan.M  Moli.Z  Peter.K
Moli.Z  Rosi.Bab    Handy.M Khan.M  Rose.M  Khan.M  Ali.J   Peter.K
Nadia.M Ali.J   Kato.Bada   Khan.M  Rose.M  Khan.M  Ali.J   Peter.K
Sarah.B Moli.z  Handy.M Khan.M  Rose.M  James.K Ali.J   Kato.Bada
 ", header = TRUE)
```

Sa you can see I have 8 ids. I want to move the ids as you can see below. For example, Ali.j is appeared in id1, id2 and id7. So in the first column, we can see id1,id2 and id7. the second column is the name and the last column is frequency based on column 1, so it is three times, Finally, I want to get the sum for the second and third column. Here is the intended outcome.

```html
ID  Name    freq
id1,id2,id7 Ali.J   3
id1 Smith.Kol   1
id1,id3,id8 Kato.Bada   3
id1,id2,id7 Moli.Z  3
id1 Nadia.M 1
id1 Sarah.B 1
id2 Koli.M  1
id2 Hoddy.G 1
id2 Ahadi.M 1
id2 Rosi.Bab    1
id3 Handy.M 1
id3 Nancy.M 1
id4,id8 Kori.Z  1
id4,id6 Khan.M  1
id5 Simon.B 1
id5 Rose.M  1
id6 James.K 1
id8 Peter.k 1
sum 18  24
```

Can we do it it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(ind ~ ., unique(stack(df)), FUN = function(x) 
           c(N = length(x), Var = toString(x)))
```

-output

```
#      values ind.N       ind.Var
#1    Ahadi.M     1           Id2
#2      Ali.J     3 Id1, Id2, Id7
#3    Handy.M     1           Id3
#4    Hoddy.G     1           Id2
#5    James.K     1           Id6
#6  Kato.Bada     3 Id1, Id3, Id8
#7     Khan.M     2      Id4, Id6
#8     koli.M     1           Id2
#9     kori.Z     2      Id4, Id8
#10    Moli.z     1           Id2
#11    Moli.Z     2      Id1, Id7
#12   Nadia.M     1           Id1
#13   Nancy.M     1           Id3
#14   Peter.K     1           Id8
#15    Rose.M     1           Id5
#16  Rosi.Bab     1           Id2
#17   Sarah.B     1           Id1
#18   Simon.B     1           Id5
#19 Smith.kol     1           Id1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  group_by(value) %>% summarise(N=n_distinct(name),
                                Var=toString(unique(name)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 3
   value         N Var          
   <fct>     <int> <chr>        
 1 Ali.J         3 Id1, Id7, Id2
 2 Kato.Bada     3 Id1, Id3, Id8
 3 Moli.Z        2 Id7, Id1     
 4 Nadia.M       1 Id1          
 5 Sarah.B       1 Id1          
 6 Smith.kol     1 Id1          
 7 Ahadi.M       1 Id2          
 8 Hoddy.G       1 Id2          
 9 koli.M        1 Id2          
10 Moli.z        1 Id2          
11 Rosi.Bab      1 Id2          
12 Handy.M       1 Id3          
13 Nancy.M       1 Id3          
14 Khan.M        2 Id6, Id4     
15 kori.Z        2 Id4, Id8     
16 Rose.M        1 Id5          
17 Simon.B       1 Id5          
18 James.K       1 Id6          
19 Peter.K       1 Id8
```

Comment: This solution is better than mine because it catches the need to count unique values.

Comment: Please see my output. can we do better?

Answer (score 1):

Using only loop (but it's probably best to learn how to use the packages from the other answers):

```
newdf = data.frame(names = unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df))))
for(i in 1:nrow(newdf)){
  index = which(apply(df,2,function(x){newdf$names[i] %in% x}))
  newdf$id[i] = paste(names(index), collapse=", ")
  newdf$frequency[i] = length(index)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution. The `pivot_longer()` function from `tidyr` takes your table and makes it into a long data.frame with each row a Name-ID pair. If we `group_by(Name)` we can `summarise()` the data by group. The `n()` function counts rows, and `toString()` converts a vector to a single character string separated by commas.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "ID", values_to = "Name") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(freq = n(),
            ID = toString(ID))
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 19 x 3
   Name       freq ID                               
   <chr>     <int> <chr>                            
 1 Ahadi.M       1 Id2                              
 2 Ali.J         5 Id1, Id7, Id2, Id7, Id7          
 3 Handy.M       3 Id3, Id3, Id3                    
 4 Hoddy.G       1 Id2                              
 5 James.K       2 Id6, Id6                         
 6 Kato.Bada     3 Id1, Id3, Id8                    
 7 Khan.M        7 Id6, Id6, Id4, Id6, Id4, Id6, Id4
 8 koli.M        1 Id2                              
 9 kori.Z        4 Id4, Id8, Id4, Id4               
10 Moli.z        1 Id2                              
11 Moli.Z        4 Id7, Id7, Id7, Id1               
12 Nadia.M       1 Id1                              
13 Nancy.M       2 Id3, Id3                         
14 Peter.K       4 Id8, Id8, Id8, Id8               
15 Rose.M        3 Id5, Id5, Id5                    
16 Rosi.Bab      1 Id2                              
17 Sarah.B       1 Id1                              
18 Simon.B       3 Id5, Id5, Id5                    
19 Smith.kol     1 Id1
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not reflect my outcome and also went wrong Plus Error: unexpected symbol in "`summarise()` ungrouping"